# Is there any way to make the "starred" section in gmail's priority inbox show both unread and read messages that are starred?

Tags: gmail

I'm a big fan of priority inbox, especially since it gives you sections just like the multiple inboxes lab. However, the sections in priority inbox are not as flexible.

I've setup my priority inbox sections as:

1. Important and unread
2. Starred
3. All Drafts
4. Everything else

That's perfect for me, except for the fact that the starred section only shows starred messages that are unread. I like marking all my mail read as soon I read it, and just starring the messages that I need to respond to (rather than keeping them unread till I act on them). Previously, I used the "is:starred" query with the multiple inboxes lab and that correctly shows messages that are read and starred.

Any idea how I get functionality like "is:starred" within a priority inbox section? Maybe there is a hidden way to specify a section as a search query instead of only choosing from that dropdown list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out.

I didn't see "In Inbox and:" at the top of the section dropdown. To get the functionality I want ("All starred") you need to choose "more options" and then click "starred".

Definitely confusing though, both items are labeled "starred" yet they are not the same.